# Hang on black screen after grub

Tags: boot, initrd

Installed Ubuntu 20.04. I can get into grub by holding down the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

After proceeding to boot the screen goes black (with the backlight on) and nothing more happens.

Adding some `echo` to the `grub` script suggests that it's running and therefore the problem is with whatever happens next.

[image]

I see:

```
  Booting a command list

*1
*3
*4
_
```

The cursor at the bottom does not blink.

Any ideas?!

**Update 1**

On the black screen <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-Fi</kbd> for $1\leq i \leq 6$ doesn't do anything.

In grub removed `quiet splash` and added `nomodeset` which made no difference.

In the Ubuntu installer if I check *Install third-party software...* then the installer freezes.

**Update 2**

Tried Debian 10.

Adding `nomodeset` *does* get past the first freeze, but then it freezes after printing

```
[  OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
```

<kbd>Ctrl-Alt-F2</kbd> does work and I can log in as `root`. Added `contrib non-free` to the package sources and tried

```
# apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree libgl1-mesa-dri libglx-mesa0 mesa-vulkan-drivers xserver-xorg-video-all
```

but no difference.

**Update 3**

Installed Ubunto 20 again.
Third party software still freezes.
Same result: <kbd>Esc</kbd> gets into `grub`, `quiet` and `splash` and `nomodeset` make no difference, and `<kbd>Ctrl-Alt-Fi</kbd> not working.

Comment: can you access tty using Alt+Ctrl+F<1-6>? Maybe it is something to do with your greeter.

Comment: Just installed Debian instead, but similar problem.

Unlike Ubuntu: removing `quiet` produces some output and then adding `nomodeset` fixes the first freeze. Now freezing at ``[ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager.`